# Trying to call a method from interface results in error "Object reference is required"

Tags: c#

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18743/Interfaces-in-C-For-Beginners)
has an error in the code for PS6... `xyz()` produces the Error:

> An Object reference is required for the non-static method.

```
class Demo : abc
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello Interfaces");
        xyz();

    }

    public void xyz()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("In xyz");
    }
}

interface abc
{
    void xyz();
}
```

Could you explain what is my `xyz()` call is it the method, property, field. I am lost on what it really is being called?

And why this does not work? When we make a new instantiate of Demo?

This does...

```
Demo obj = new Demo();
obj.xyz();
```

Comment: The first part is a method. Maybe it's a good idea to learn about classes and other basic C# stuff first before starting a specific tutorial about interfaces. The rest of the question is a bit vague(r). It's not clear to me what works, what doesn't work, and how it doesn't work. Do you get any error? If so, please add them to your question.

Comment: thanks @GolezTrol I did forget the error it gave me in the question. I have been trying to build better apps by learning OOP more in detail, I think I have a good idea of classes, but so much of it is just a difficult thing to understand like this has me so confused on why a person would want an interface to encapsulate something they have to make public in the method that uses the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xyz` is a method. An instance method to be precise, so let me try to explain why you cannot call it from the static method Main, and how to solve that.

A class definition defines which methods (and properties, etc). If you make an instance of it (`new Demo`), you've got an object. An object refers to the class so you know what functionality it contains, and it has it's own block of data in which you can store values, so 10 instances can contain 10 different values.

So for instance:

```
class Demo {
  public string name;
}

var a = new Demo();
a.name = 'John';
var b = new Demo();
b.name = 'Bob';
// At this point, a.name is still John. a and b each have their own name.
```

A normal method is an instance method. It can reach and use those instance variables. So, extending the previous example, you could do this:

```
class Demo {
  public string name;
  public void WhoAmI() {
    System.Console.WriteLine(this.name);
  }
}

var a = new Demo();
a.name = 'John';
var b = new Demo();
b.name = 'Bob';
a.WhoAmI(); // outputs 'John'
```

Now, apart from those instance variables and instance methods, you also got static *members* (members are variables, methods, properties...). static means that they don't belong to an instance, but to the class definition. There is only one of them in the application. They belong to the class rather than the instance.

Now, the object instance knows what class it belongs to. If you make a variable `var a = new Demo()`, then `a` knows it is a `Demo`, so from it or through it, you can call a static method like `Main` in you example.

However, in a static method, there if no knowledge of the instance it belongs to. After all, there doesn't even need to be an instance. You can call `a.Main()`, but you could also call `Demo.Main()`.
Because of this, you cannot use instance variables, and neither call instance methods. Since `xyz` is an instance method, it cannot be called from the static method `Main`.

Now the solution to this could be to make `xyz` static. After all, it doesn't refer to other instance members. However, interfaces don't allow this, so this would throw another error. An interface describes what an instance looks like and doesn't support static member. This is a design decision in C#.

So, alternatively, you may introduce an extra static implementation and call that from the interface method too. This way, the interface implementation can still call the static version, as can the Main method:

```
class Demo : abc
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello Interfaces");
        zyx();
    }

    public static void zyx() {
      System.Console.WriteLine("In zyx");
    }

    public void xyz()
    {
        zyx();
    }
}

interface abc
{
    void xyz();
}
```

About interfaces. Is saw you asking this in the comments. There are many uses for interfaces, although their explanation is a bit out of scope here. Note however that you don't *need* interfaces all the time for every class. So if there is no need for an interface in your specific implementation, you don't need the extra method that I introduces either. The reason why CodeProject is making you implement an interface is because it's the topic of the tutorial. ;)

They briefly summed up the advantage of an interface in the introduction of their tutorial:

> Interfaces in C# provide a way to achieve runtime polymorphism. Using
>   interfaces we can invoke functions from different classes through the
>   same Interface reference, whereas using virtual functions we can
>   invoke functions from different classes in the same inheritance
>   hierarchy through the same reference

So, if you would have different kinds of Demo classes, you could extend them from each other:

```
class BaseDemo {
  abstract void xyz() {
    System.Console.WriteLine("in Basedemo.xyz");
  }
}

class SpecificDemo1: BaseDemo {
  override void xyz() {
    System.Console.WriteLine("in SpecificDemo1.xyz");
  }
}

class SpecificDemo2: BaseDemo {
  override void xyz() {
    System.Console.WriteLine("in SpecificDemo2.xyz");
  }
}
```

Now, you could declare a method like this:

```
class DemoUser {
  static void CallXyz(BaseDemo d) {
    d.xyz();
  }
}

var a = new SpecificDemo2();
DemoUser.CallXyz(a);
```

CallXyz accepts variables of type SpecificDemo1 and SpecificDemo2. The reason this works is that its parameter is declared of type BaseDemo, so it accepts instances of all decendants of BaseDemo.

However, making big hierarchies of classes to support this, is just not useful and maintainable, so that's where interfaces come in. You can capture a small piece of functionality in an interface, and use that.

Example, in the code below, I've declared two functionalities, Foo and Bar, in interfaces. Three classes implement one or more of these interfaces. The classes themselves are not related. They *can* be, but it doesn't matter from the interface's point of view.

```
class Foo: IFoo {
  public void DoFoo() {
    System.Console.WriteLine('Foo is fooing');
  }
}
class Bar: IBar {
  public void DoBar() {
    System.Console.WriteLine('Bar is barring');
  }
}

class FooBar: IFoo, IBar {
  public void DoFoo() {
    System.Console.WriteLine('FooBar is fooing');
  }
  public void DoBar() {
    System.Console.WriteLine('FooBar is barring');
  }
}

IFoo {
  void DoFoo() {
}
IBar {
  void DoBar() {
}
```

Now, if there is a method that wants to 'Bar' something, it can accept an IBar parameter. Such a method accepts instances of Bar and of Foobar.

With normal inheritance this would not be achievable. You would have to inherit FooBar from both Foo and Bar, which is not possible, or you would have to make FooBar the base class, in which case you would have to declare both methods in the base class already. This also implies that a Foo instance would be able to pass as a Bar and vice versa. This is not desirable.

Using interfaces, you can simply declare a small functionality and implement it in *any* class you like.

Comment: you are the best. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Could you explain what is my `xyz()` call is it the method,property, field.

It is a [`Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx).

> Why this does not work ?

Because `xyz()` is not defined as [`static`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/static) and can not be `static` because the modifier static is not valid for interface member declaration. So you should create instance like this:

```
Demo obj = new Demo();
obj.xyz();
```

***Edit*:**

> Why would we use the interface at all ?

With interface not only you guarantee *standardization*, *flexibility*, *scalability*, *extensibility*, *maintainability*, *reusability*, *testability* and *power* but also one of the main reason the interfaces are used in C# is because C# [doesn't support multiple (class) inheritance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/07/why-doesn-t-c-support-multiple-inheritance.aspx).

Comment: I guess the confusing part is it is a method in the Interface class and a method in the Demo class but the interface class is simply just (?) pointing to the method in the class that is interfacing it ( ie.. Demo : abcd )

I've made filter classes before and that pattern sounds similar in my head but somehow this concept seems lost to me. Why would we use the interface at all ?

Comment: @RiePwe ... Check my updated answer for you question about interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void xyz()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("In xyz");
}
```

- public means it is a public method and other classes can interact
  with it.
- void means it returns void a.k.a. nothing
- xyz  is the name
  of the method
- () is where parameters go, but here there are no parameters that the method is called with so it is empty
- between the curled parenthesis is the code block which is also named function or method body

Main method is flagged in c-like languages to be where code execute starts so you should start from there.